# how to roll back my chrome extension sync?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I had the myetherwallet chrome extension on 2 different computers (1 laptop, 1 desktop, both logged into chrome with the same google account.

I had 5 wallets on my laptop that I couldn't see on the desktop even though I was using the same google account.

I accidentally pressed the sync button feature in google extension setting from the desktop and now I can't see the wallets from my laptop, they are gone.

I never recorded the private key's for these private wallets.

Do you know of a way to rollback Chrome extension history or otherwise recover the wallet data?  I am on Mac, will a system rollback restore the local profile Chrome data?

Please help if you can.

Comment: It might restore but make sure to disable your network connection when launching Chrome.

Comment: how do I restore? I use mac. Can you explain a bit?  Thanks.

Comment: I think I didn't do system rollback (like timemachine).. Is there other way to do it? 
I saved the chrome file